# Will the executor will be release before finishing the workflow in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

CDH 5.14 Cluster is having

```
spark.executor.memory=10G
spark.executor.cores=2
spark.executor.instances=10
mode: yarn-cluster
```

I am initiating 6 workflows with 2-node, 2-core and 2GB each. The first 5 workflows will be assigned the executors by Yarn,
and 6th workflow would be in queue.

My question is if one of the jobs is finished in existing 5 jobs, the the executor be released before completing the entire workflow and that executor is picked up by 6th Workflow.

Comment: Is `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true` in your cluster?

Comment: No i didn't configured this in my conf

Comment: In that case ("static allocation") executors allocated to a Spark application stay with it for the duration of that application. In dynamic allocation scenario, executors can come and go. By the way, I think CDH has dynamic allocation enabled by default.